# Zend Framework Form load error

Tags: zend-framework

I just moved my ZF application from one server to another, and everything is loading smoothly, except for forms. It just throws this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Form_Cms_AddForm' not found in /xx/application/modules/admin/controllers/CmsController.php on line 42
```

The modules, models, controllers are loaded as they should be, but no forms. What could have gone wrong, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you moving from a Win Server to a *nix server? Remember the filenames are case sensitive, so that could be the problem.

Comment: Thanks! My Forms folder was further divided into subfolders, and the "Cms" folder was called "cms", so this solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add in boostrap:

```
public function _initModules()
{
$autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => 'Yourmodule_',
        'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__) . '/modules/yourmodule',
    ));
}
```

That solve your(and my) problem =);

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your application.ini file is diferenton the server? Maybe the evironment variable being on production it changes something for you?
And are you sure everything is the same?